# i am having a matrix in ssrs with 12 month columns and category with date as below.How to find the difference between first row and second row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

```
Category/Date    jul    aug    sep    oct    nov    dec    ...jan
AA on 2020jun    5       6       3      8     2     7    ... 4
AA on 2020May    7       3        2      6     5     5    ....7
Difference       -2      1        1      2    -3     2    ...-3
```

I am using wcf query to fetch the data.The dataset looks like

```
category -AA
Date - 2020Jun
Month1  4
Month12  7
Month11  2
Month10  8
```

i am using a switch statement  like below to display each column value

```
switch(Reportdate.Month(jun 2020) = 1, Fields.Month1.Value,
       Reportdate.Month = 12, Fields.Month12.Value)
```

The problem i am facing is with finding the difference in each column

Comment: Hi @Sangeetha. It would be very helpful if you could edit your question and [add some formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your code to improve the readability.

Comment: Done .. Let me know if u find it still difficult